# Secured by url spring security

Tags: security, url, grails, spring-security

In my project I'm doing a server to server call. So I want to create a method that can only be accessed from a server with a specific url. Is it possible to do that using spring security? If it's not, what are the best alternatives?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [IP Address Restrictions of](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/ip.html) Spring Security plugin